# Why does my baby have bubbles around the mouth?

Tags: infant

My infant sometimes bubbles from the mouth. When he does this he doesn't seem to be distressed but I end up constantly having to wipe his mouth. Could this be because I am not burping him enough? Does this happen to other people?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saliva and breathing sometimes can be a recipe for bubbles. It is quite normal.
Take a picture of it when a large one pops up and have  laugh about it with your kid when he grows up.

Comment: Love this...I do the same with my boys.

Answer (score 4):

It happened with my kids.  They were always drooling, bubbling, and dripping with snot.  Slugs are cleaner.

Comment: +1 for "Slugs are cleaner." Very true! Doesn't matter what bodily fluid issues you may have had pre-parenting, you'll get over them fast once you have a newborn!